werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'newusername'
# Route: User Registration
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    newusername = request.form['newusername']
    userid = request.form['personid']    
    surname = request.form['surname']    
    gender = request.form['gender']
    section = request.form['section']
    designation = request.form['designation']
    userimagefolder = 'static/faces/'+newusername+'_'+str(userid)
    if not os.path.isdir(userimagefolder):
        os.makedirs(userimagefolder)
    i, j = 0, 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while 1:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        faces = extract_faces(frame)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 20), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, f'Images Captured: {i}/{nimgs}', (30, 30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 20), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            if j % 5 == 0:
                name = newusername+'_'+str(i)+'.jpg'
                cv2.imwrite(userimagefolder+'/'+name, frame[y:y+h, x:x+w])
                i += 1
            j += 1
        if j == nimgs*5:
            break
        #cv2.imshow('Adding new User', frame)
        
        return render_template('register.html', success=f"User {newusername} {surname} registered successfully!")
    else:
        return render_template('register.html', error="No face detected. Please try again.")
        session.add(name)
        session.commit()
        return render_template('register.html')

I am trying to add a user but getting the stated error. I have shared my @Route code for user registration. Can anyone please provide their valuable guidance for resolving this issue.

You do not differentiate between GET and POST requests in your route. For this reason, the key newusername is not included in the dict for a GET request. If the error also occurs for a POST request, the name attribute for the input field within the template is not assigned correctly. I notice that you are using the server's webcam to create an image of the user. This may work in your test environment, but under real conditions you should use the client-side webcam using JavaScript.
